# Is it possible to crush a human neck?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, combat, cybernetics

One of the character's in my story is a overly-augmented augmented warrior (has a terminator-esque endoskeleton beneath layers of dermal plating and everything) and at one point grabs someone's throat in one hand and crushes it "like a disposable paper cup". Is this possible with those kinds of augmentations? What exactly would the results of such a move be like (aside from the death part)?

Comment: @JohnO Ah I see, thank you for the answer! Much appreciated :)

Comment: @JohnO Is there a way for you to make your answer official instead of just a comment? I wanted to upvote it

Comment: @David Thank you David! I appreciate the input

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with world building?

Comment: People die from having their tracheas crushed quite frequently. It’s not unheard of for victims of violent rapists or serial killers to be strangled so severely that the trachea is crushed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure you even need an augmented human for this.

## Disclaimer, please don't try this at home!

*Or ehm, anywhere really...*

Of course, you run into an issue of size, as the comments point out, a human hand won't fully fit around a human neck. Realistically, you would reach roughly as far as the sternocleidomastoid muscle, [here depicted in green.](https://thumbor.kenhub.com/eLpUQvvztJ44cAggDP5zuGN8U8I=/fit-in/800x800/filters:fill(FFFFFF,true):watermark(/images/logo_url.png,-10,-10,0):format(jpeg)/images/anatomy_term/sternocleidomastoid-muscle-12/hbimApe3IQfTimfNbNgnBw_sternocleido_mastoid.png)

This means everything in front of it is fair game. If you were to really dig in your fingers and get a good grip, one could in theory crush or rip out the windpipe and a good number of other essentials. Add some augmented human to that, and they shouldn't struggle at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for the diagram! Really helpful for giving the other answers more context. Thanks Plutain!

Comment: @Millennium glad it helped. To be honest writing this answer gave me the creeps.

Comment: @Plutian I've had that happen with some questions about necromancy and such.  I'd like to think I'm a nice guy, but some of the answers I have written have made me doubt that over the years.

Comment: @PaulTIKI-MonicacomeHome I suppose everyone has a dark side. But how you act on it is what really makes a difference. When you don't feel the guilt anymore is when you should really start to worry. Glad to know it's not just me though!

Comment: @Plutian  I think that saying that a human hand won't fully fit around a human neck are exaggerated. One of my hands won't go around my neck but 2 meet and overlap a little.  I remember being impressed by the big hands of a normal sized man in a movie.  He picked up a 12-year-old boy by the waist and his hands almost met around it.  I figure that the boy's waist was over twice as wide as his neck, so that man could have wrapped a single hand around his neck.  A normal 12-year-old boy is bigger than over half the humans who ever lived got to be, with a neck almost as wide as an adult's.